# Using awk to print format the output

Tags: linux, awk

This is the awk script I have written:

```
BEGIN{ print "Working" }
{
    awk "$1=$1" FS=";" OFS="\n" questions.txt > aa.txt
}
```

The file has text like:

```
B-001-002-002;An Amateur Radio Operator Certificate is valid >for:;life;five years;three years;one year
```

Using FS and OFS, I am able to split it into separate lines. The code works in cli, but I want to write it in a script and be able to run it.

My code is:

```
awk '$1=$1' FS=";" OFS="\n" filename
```

This works in the cli, but when i am not sure how to use it in a script.

Desired Output:

> 1. B-001-002-002
>
> An Amateur Radio Operator Certificate is valid for:
>
> a) life
>
> b) five years
>
> c) three years
>
> d) one year

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried copying those exact lines into a file? Because it works.

Comment: Should i use it inside the BEGIN block, or just in a separate block? I tried doing it.
When i copy the same code and run it, it gives a syntax error: Syntax error at or near =

Comment: Your command works the same for me whether it's inside a script or on the command line. I copied `awk '$1=$1' FS=";" OFS="\n" filename`, put it in a file named `scr`, ran `chmod +x scr`, and then ran `./scr` and got the output from the semicolon-delimited file as individual lines.

Comment: Why on earth would you post your script as an image instead of as text that we could execute to test it??? Anyway - you're trying to call awk from inside awk, I suspect you do not understand the difference between awk and shell. Read the first chapter of the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to solve this problem and then read the rest of it before attempting any more awk programming,

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply. This is my first time in stackoverflow. didnt know things work.

Comment: The code in the image you posted (which I've edited and put in the main text of your question) is not valid awk. your call to awk inside an awk script is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little more than just changing the delimiters.

```
$ awk -F';' 'BEGIN{split("x;x;a;b;c;d;e",c)} 
                  {print NR". " $1; print $2; 
                   for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print c[i] ") " $i}' file

1. B-001-002-002
An Amateur Radio Operator Certificate is valid for:
a) life
b) five years
c) three years
d) one year
```